# tridion translations without sdl products

Tags: translation, tridion

I have been trying to find an example some where on web on how to do translations in Tridion. I had no luck finding anything except mentioning of Translation Manager. Can someone point to a resource or best practices on how this can be done?

More details: I want to know how people send content for translations and then get it back into tridion. I saw some posts talking about event system. I am looking for a big picture start — localize — export — import — maintenance phases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really the wrong place to ask this question, but I think it deserves a proper answer anyway.

SDL is (among other things) the "Global Information Management" company. Everything SDL does has a language/localization/globalization aspect to it. Including, of course, its translation tools and services.

As such, SDL has created and maintained (for many years) connectors to various CM platforms, and obviously SDL Tridion has a great integration story here. Good details about how it works [here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=802), courtesy of Robert Curlette.

If you're trying to integrate Tridion with other language vendors, I suggest you ask the language vendors for such a connector. The Tridion connector was available from SDL before the Tridion acquisition, I suspect that if other language vendors are serious about their connectivity to WCM platforms, they will also offer a connector to Tridion.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to go with Translation Manager.  I think the only solution is to localise your component in respective publication and do manual entry of publication/country specific content.
For translating your content only you can take help of any third party tools (search over Google).
even in that case also you have to do manual content entry in  tridion cms.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the good comments from Ram and Nuno - You might want to investigate using the Workflow Engine from SDL Tridion. It offers the ability to write your own automated activities (e.g. Send or receive an item for translation via email or web service). This may be an effective solution for you, assuming there are no connectors available for the the  translation services you intend to use.